# Optimization query

Tags: mysql, database, performance, optimization

I've created a Database of a veterinary clinic. This DB contains the tables: Drug (code), Animal(id), Prescription (id_animal, code_drug, start_date, end_date). I've to optimizate this query because is quite slow, but i don't know how:

```
      SELECT D.Code, P.Administration, P.End_date

      FROM Drug D, Prescription P, Animal A

      WHERE P.Id_animal = A.Id AND P.Code_drug = D.Code AND A.id = 3 AND (P.End_date >= CURDATE() OR P.End_date IS NULL)

      ORDER BY P.End_date;
```

Comment: What indexes do you have defined on the tables?

Comment: First off, use an inner join rather than a cross join.

Comment: please run an `EXPLAIN SELECT....` on your query and post and also `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for all of the tables, this way we will know what MySQL is doing when you execute the query, and what to do about it.

Answer (score 1):

I would rework your query using inner joins over cross joins:

```
select d.code,
       p.administration,
       p.end_date
from drug as d
inner join prescription as p
on d.code = p.code_drug
inner join animal as a
on p.id_animal = a.id
where p.end_date >= curdate()
    or p.end_date is null
```

There's also a good chance that you need proper indexes on the tables but that's hard to tell without knowing the structure of your tables and exactly how they were created.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT  P.Administration, P.End_date, 
      ( SELECT  CODE
            FROM  Drug
            WHERE  D.code = p.Code_drug
      ) CODE
    FROM  Prescription P
    -- JOIN  Animal A  ON P.Id_animal = A.Id
    WHERE  P.Id_animal = 3
      AND  (P.End_date >= CURDATE()
              OR  P.End_date IS NULL
           )
    ORDER BY  P.End_date;
```

You are joining animal table unnecessarily as you are searching for animal id 3

Comment: Add to `Prescription`: `INDEX(Id_animal, End_date)`